# Empty plot issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

As you can see in the picture attached when I execute my code I get two graphs and one of them is empty. I only need one so what is wrong with my code below?

```
kmf_par_modele = KaplanMeierFitter()

duration = iot_df_2.duree
observed = iot_df_2.batterie_0

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 2, sharey = True, figsize=(12,15))

for modele_capteur, ax in zip(modele_capteur, axes.flatten()):
     idx = iot_df_2.modele_objet == modele_capteur
     kmf_par_modele.fit(duration[idx], observed[idx])
     kmf_par_modele.plot(ax=ax, legend=False)

     ax.annotate("Moyenne = {:.0f} mois".format(kmf_par_modele.median_), xy = (.47, .85), xycoords = "axes fraction")
     ax.set_xlabel("")
     ax.set_title(modele_capteur) 
     ax.set_xlim(0,25)
     ax.set_ylim(0,1)

fig.tight_layout()
fig.text(0.5, -0.01, "Timeline (Mois)", ha="center")
fig.text(-0.01, 0.5, "Probabilité qu'un ERS_C02 ait toujours de la batterie",  va="center", rotation="vertical")
fig.suptitle("Courbe de longévité pour le capteur ERS_C02",
             fontsize=20)
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.92)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Just use a single column: Use `ncols=1` in `fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, sharey = True, figsize=(12,15))`. Needless to say, you are seeing two plots because you have defined 1 row and 2 cols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, you just need to specify one single plot (subplot) if you only need one. I am answering because you don't need to flatten your `axes` instance because you just use a single figure. Here is how you can do it  alternatively:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,15))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) # 111 means 1 row, 1 column ad 1st subplot (here only 1)

for modele_capteur in modele_capteur: # just loop over your modele_capteur
     idx = iot_df_2.modele_objet == modele_capteur
     kmf_par_modele.fit(duration[idx], observed[idx])
     kmf_par_modele.plot(ax=ax, legend=False)

     ax.annotate("Moyenne = {:.0f} mois".format(kmf_par_modele.median_), xy = (.47, .85), xycoords = "axes fraction")
     ax.set_xlabel("")
     ax.set_title(modele_capteur)
     ax.set_xlim(0,25)
     ax.set_ylim(0,1)
```

Comment: You awesome! Thanks.